# Git push to local repository

Tags: git, repository, push

I make two repositories on my machine, I follow this [guide](http://michael.otacoo.com/linux-2/setting-a-git-server-with-dropbox/). And in the last step I get this error:

```
elta compression using up to 2 threads.
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
error: corrupt loose object '6dcf134fd4eb663f01bc1088b12f7cf389254636'
fatal: loose object 6dcf134fd4eb663f01bc1088b12f7cf389254636 (stored in .git/objects/6d/cf134fd4eb663f01bc1088b12f7cf389254636) is corrupt
error: failed to push some refs to
```

I removed and create repository from the beginning several times, but it did not help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use github also, but in windows. I had 2 major problems while pushing at least till I found my problem. Try looking at both of theses solutions

1. The URL is case sensitive. So make sure your remote's url is exactly correct including (upper/lower case letters).
2. For some reason (never bother to figure out why) you may also need to pull from github before pushing. To this date I have had to do this for every project (at least before the first push).

So:

```
git pull <remote name> <branch name>
git push <remote name> <branch name>
```

Most likly in your case:

```
remote name = origin
branch name = master
```

And just to itterate the entire process.
Did you do all theses steps:

```
git init 
git add .
git commit -m "inital commit"
git remote add <device name> URL
git pull <device Name> master
git push <decive Name> master
```

Also note that many of the git walkthroughs try to get fancy with the remotes. I would go to the very basics at least until you get that working. So to beat a dead horse!

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<account name>/<repo name>.git
```

Or in my case it would look like this:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/DanielHaro/my_app.git
```

but I hate the remote name origin so I actually use:

```
git remote add tron https://github.com/DanielHaro/my_app.git
```

Which is so cute becase later you get to use:

```
git push tron master
```